# IOrderedEnumerable<XElement> returning NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm currently having a problem in which I get a NullReferenceException from the following method:

```
    public void LoadValueXML()
    {
        XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(@"config.xml");
        Items = myxml.Element("Values").Elements("Item").OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID"));
        ItemsLength = Items.Count();
    }
```

The fourth line in the method in which I try to set the Items variable is generating the exception. My XML document is formatted like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Values>
  <Item ID="1" Type="Command" Value="330MV,60HZ"/>
  <Item ID="2" Type="Command" Value="600MV,13KHZ"/>
  <Item ID="3" Type="Command" Value="3.3V,60HZ"/>
  <Item ID="4" Type="Notification" Value="Look At This!!!" />
</Values>
```

I can't seem to find the problem. It would appear that everything loads fine into the XDocument. In the debugger it shows XDocument isn't null but when I try to set Items it still throws an exception. Thanks in advance for any help solving this problem.

As a side note: Trying XDocument.Parse() instead of XDocument.Load() returns a `"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."` Exception.

Edit:

After following cdhowie's advice my current method looks like this:

```
    public void LoadValueXML()
    {
        XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(@"config.xml");
        var values = myxml.Element("Values");
        var items = values.Elements("Item");
        Items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID"));
        ItemsLength = Items.Count();
    }
```

`values` is null and items is returning "Enumeration yielded no results". It's no longer throwing an exception but it still isn't working.

EDIT 2:

New method following Jeyaram J's advice:

```
    public void LoadValueXML()
    {
        XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(@"config.xml");
        var items = myxml.Root.Elements("Item");
        Items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID"));
        ItemsLength = Items.Count();
    }
```

It works partially but throws an "At least one object must implement IComparable." exception.

Comment: Regarding Parse() vs Load(): does the document have a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning?  Perhaps Load() is stripping out the BOM before feeding it to the parser, but whatever you use to load the file into a string is not stripping it out.

Comment: Parse() is for XML itself as a string.

Comment: you need to parse x.Attribute("ID").Value to integer. Check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Root instead of Element.

```
public void LoadValueXML()
{
    XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load("config.xml");
    Items = myxml.Root.Elements("Item").OrderBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("ID"));
    ItemsLength = Items.Count();
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: This works at least partially. It's throwing an error "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Comment: @ZachSmith Since this is the closest, I'll modify his instead of creating an almost exact same answer.  Add `(int)` before the `x.Attribute("ID")` to convert the attribute to an integer.

Comment: @ZachSmith The reason you need the IComparable is that OrderBy doesn't know how to sort Attribute's automatically, but it does with integers.

Answer (score 2):

You  should add `.Value` when ordering on attribute. You wanna sort by `ID`'s value, don't you ?

The strange thing is that I've got an `ArgumentException` with your code (`at least one object must implement IComparable`), not a `NRE`...

```
Items = myxml.Element("Values")
             .Elements("Item")
             .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value);
```

or if you want numeric sorting

```
OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("ID").Value);
```

Comment: It still throws the same error. The farthest down InnerException is still "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I split it up like cdhowie suggested and the NRE went away. Odd... Now I'm just curious what was causing it.

Comment: @ZachSmith so you've got a problem with `Items` or `ItemsLength`, not with the xml parsing... Where do they come from ?

Comment: Oh. No. Scratch my earlier comment. I've still got a problem. Ran it in debug and value is still setting to null. It's just not throwing an exception.

Comment: @ZachSmith hmmm. Could you give, at least, the Type  of `Items` and `ItemCount` ?

Comment: `IOrderedEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> Items;
 int ItemsLength;`

Comment: Tested with these variables, with my code (without `ToList()`) and it works perfectly. Are you sure that the given Xml is the one you use ?

Comment: @ZachSmith this is the error I got in my answer. Add `.Value`

Comment: I'm still curious. Does the fact that Root.Elements() works give any hint as to what the problem could possibly have been?

Comment: @ZachSmith Well, they were in fact two (totally) distinct problems. Root was the first to be managed, before detecting the second (.Value missing). Ask Jeyaram J for the Root problem, I can't reproduce it (will take a look).

Answer (score 2):

When debugging something like this, consider breaking each chained method call out into its own statement.

```
var values = myxml.Element("Values");
var items = values.Elements("Item");
Items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID"));
```

The line the exception points to should now clearly indicate which method returned null, and you will also be able to inspect the locals in the debugger to verify this.

Comment: What's really strange is that this doesn't throw the exception. It works.

Comment: @ZachSmith even  if you add `ItemsLength = Items.Count();` ?

Comment: It appears it's just not throwing an exception. I ran the debugger and values is set to null and Items is empty once the method's been run.

Comment: @ZachSmith First, try to add a ToList() at the end of the OrderBy. Tell us what happens.

Comment: Added ToList(). Still getting "Enumeration yielded no results".

Comment: I tried it but loading the xml with XDocument.Parse("<MY XML />") and its working just fine .. wierd.!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I'm debugging unexpected LINQ problems, my first step is usually to break out each individual step. For example:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"config.xml");
var valuesElement = document.Element("Values");
var itemElements = valuesElement.Elements("Item");
var idAttributes = itemElements.Select(x => x.Attribute("ID"));
var orderedItems = itemElements.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID"));
var orderedItemsCount = orderedItems.Count();
```

Stepping through that in the debugger like you're already doing will usually reveal the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void loadXMl()
        {
            string abcd = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<Values>
  <Item ID=""1"" Type=""Command"" Value=""330MV,60HZ""/>
  <Item ID=""2"" Type=""Command"" Value=""600MV,13KHZ""/>
  <Item ID=""3"" Type=""Command"" Value=""3.3V,60HZ""/>
  <Item ID=""4"" Type=""Notification"" Value=""Look At This!!!"" />
</Values>";

            XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(abcd);//Parse(abcd);
            var Items = myxml.Element("Values");
           var abc =   Items.Elements("Item");
            var ordered =   abc.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("ID").Value));
            var ItemsLength = ordered.Count();
        }
```